# What does 'corrupt value' mean on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios

I'm writing C++ on my iOS app. When I call a `v->assign(anotherVec.begin(), anotherVec.end())` it always show me `malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fe87824ea00: probably modified after being freed. Corrupt value: 0x0`. `v` is a `vector<double>` pointer, the vector size is 0 before it crashes. The `anotherVec` is also `vector<double>`, it's size is 208. The freed object address differs every time. The app memory seems sufficient.

Here is the crash function and position in STL vector, I paste this just to show where it crashes in STL code:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
template <class _ForwardIterator>
typename enable_if
<
    __is_cpp17_forward_iterator<_ForwardIterator>::value &&
    is_constructible<
       _Tp,
       typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator>::reference>::value,
    void
>::type
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::assign(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
{
    size_type __new_size = static_cast<size_type>(_VSTD::distance(__first, __last));
    if (__new_size <= capacity())
    {
        _ForwardIterator __mid = __last;
        bool __growing = false;
        if (__new_size > size())
        {
            __growing = true;
            __mid =  __first;
            _VSTD::advance(__mid, size());
        }
        pointer __m = _VSTD::copy(__first, __mid, this->__begin_);
        if (__growing)
            __construct_at_end(__mid, __last, __new_size - size());
        else
            this->__destruct_at_end(__m);
    }
    else
    {
        __vdeallocate();
        __vallocate(__recommend(__new_size));              // Crashes here!!!!!!
        __construct_at_end(__first, __last, __new_size);
    }
    __invalidate_all_iterators();
}
```

I'm running this with Apple Clang 12.0.x and 13.0.x, Xcode. My compile options are `-Os --std=c++11 -fPIC -pthread -fno-exceptions`. It occurs about 0.01% percent with our users,  with different data, iphones and iOS versions.

My macOS version is `12.1`.

So I would like to know:

1. What is `Corrupt value: 0x0` mean? I have searched for several hours but found no explanations for this.
2. Is there any way to monitor which code visited or modified a certain memory address? And how?
3. What else can I do with this crash? Since I can't make a minimal reproducible example, I'm asking just for train of thoughts or tools to analyse.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This appears to be standard library code, which is not going to help.

Comment: @FredLarson Sorry but I can't provide a minimal reproducible example. It just crashes in my production app, which has 100+ pods, hundreds developers working on them, and I'm not familiar with most of them. If I just create a demo app, with a single controller, and I call that function the same way in that controller and with the same data, the crash not happens.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Without being able to duplicate your results there's little we can do to help. Perhaps you can employ tools like [valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) or [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) to assist you in pinpointing where things start going wrong.

Comment: How tightly do you validate the inputs from the other modules? Maybe someone is sending data in a fashion you don't expect or is outright wrong. It is also possible that a bug in another module is being exposed by yours. It really sucks when a buffer overrun  or rogue pointer in someone else's code smashes your module's data.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't know. But there are other c++ libs in the app. Before my lib was added to the app, they didn't crash. When my lib crashes, they don't crash. I shut down the switch to make my objective-c code don't call my lib, they still don't crash. So I tend to think it's my bug, not the others'. BTW, this is the first time I know valgrind can be used on iOS. I'll try it. Thanks so much!

Comment: It's really hard to say in the nightmare case. Say Module X has a bug that, without your module, smashes a bit of valid memory where no one sees the problem, and then along comes your module which changes the memory layout enough to push something important into the kill zone. That said, start by proving that your module's not the villain.  The bug is probably in your code, but A) you haven't figured out the right set of inputs to expose it or B) without Module X your module's the one writing into valid memory that no one cares enough about to look at closely.

Comment: Run under *Address Sanitizer*. On Xcode, this is easy, there is a checkbox in *Diagnostics* tab of scheme dialog right for that. Forget about Valgrind, this tool only runs on Linux.

Comment: Using *Address Sanitizer* I found there is one module by c++ has heap buffer overflow problem. I‘ll contact them. If crash eventually solves, I’ll be back to give an answer. Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

The *Address Sanitizer* is such a sharp tool. Using it on my isolate demo app, it shows several memory problems, one of them is the `anotherVec` may cause an index out of bound problem on certain cases. With it fixed, the `assign` crash goes away. With all problems fixed, crashes we collected in my module become unreproducible on the main app.

With *ASan* I even find more problems with other modules in my app. I announced my co-workers about them, and it also fixes their crashes.

However, I still don't find what does `Corrupt value: 0x0` mean. Any info is welcomed, thx very much!